# Driver is not able to find web element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi,

I have the below source. The driver is not able to click on the text
area with the name "comment".  Wondering if the span id has anything
to do with this ! Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<TD vAlign=top>
   <TEXTAREA style="DISPLAY: none" class=textinput rows=10 cols=50 name=comment>
   </TEXTAREA>
   <SPAN id=_editor_toolbar>
```

Comment: <TD vAlign=top><TEXTAREA style="DISPLAY: none" class=textinput rows=10 cols=50 name=comment></TEXTAREA><SPAN id=_editor_toolbar>

Comment: do you want to click or type in the text area? And what is the error message you are seeing?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to interact with an element on the web page with webdriver, this element should become displayed first, while your *textarea* isn't: `style="DISPLAY: none"`